# Node and async/await, promises … which solution is best?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

Working with Node and Express with Babel and trying to figure out the best approach between async/await and promises.

Key requirements:

- to be able to pass my own error
- not to cause blocking
- to approach the problem more ES6/ES7 way

I came out with these:

Promises:

```
loadByIdPromises: function (req, res, next, _id) {
  console.log('loadByIdc: ', _id);
  Artwork.loadById( { _id } )
    .then( (artwork) => {
      req.artwork = artwork;
      next();
    })
    .catch( (err) => next(new NoDataError('cannot find by ID')));
}
```

Async/Await:

```
loadByIdAsync: async function (req, res, next, _id) {
  console.log('loadByIdb: ', _id);
  try {
    req.artwork = await Artwork.loadById( { _id } );
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(new NoDataError('cannot find by ID'));
  }
}
```

or Async/Await with wrapper

```
let wrap = fn => (...args) => fn(...args).catch(args[2]);
loadByIdAsyncWrap: wrap( async function (req, res, next, _id) {
  console.log('loadByIda: ', _id);
  req.artwork = await Artwork.loadById( { _id } );
  next();
}),
```

Promises seems to be clean but may lead to cascading when things go complicated. But has a nice and clean error handling.

Async/Await seems clean but I cant figure out how to throw error from await other way than the whole try/catch thing.

Async/Await with wrapper seems simple and (at least in this case - node express router) handle error well (but without possibility to set my own). But wrapper is specific to req,res,next params and it seems to me to be something foreign (like extra divs in html before our css2/3 bliss).

What approach to choose? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Did you look at koa: https://github.com/koajs/koa ?

Comment: you've a potential problem in your Promise based version, and perhaps in the others - any exception thrown in the call to `next()` might end up propagated back up the chain.  You probably want `load().then(do_stuff).then(next, (err) => next(new Error))`

Comment: What's wrong with using `try`/`catch` for error handling?

Comment: @Sergey_Ksenofontov Yes, I've seen it, it looks great but I'd like to stay with the majority (express) :)

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak I've got it. I have to move the `next()` from `.then(do_stuff)` block to the last `.then`, right? The wrap function exposes the same problem I made manually, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Promise approach, since `async / await` aren't anywhere near mainstream yet.

However I see a potential problem in that your invocation of `next()` is *inside* the initial block meaning that you could have a successful first phase, then call `next()`, but then if *that* throws an error that isn't caught the call stack will go back up a level, with that error getting caught by your first `.catch()` block.  You'd then be generating that `cannot find by ID` error even though the real error was in the `next()` handler.

I would suggest this, instead:

```
function (req, res, next, _id) {
  console.log('loadByIdc: ', _id);
  Artwork.loadById( { _id } )
    .then((artwork) => req.artwork = artwork)
    .then(next, (err) => next(new NoDataError('cannot find by ID')));
}
```

This still leaves you with an issue over how to `.catch` any exception that might be thrown by `next`, but at least you won't be mislead by the point at which that exception is caught.

Comment: The error handling aspect is new to me, thanks @Alnitak . I'd upvote your answer but I can't.

Comment: *"This still leaves you with an issue over how to .catch any exception that might be thrown by `next`"* It will be caught and turned into a rejection in the promise returned by `then`. The code above should either handle rejections (via `.catch(err => ...)`) or pass on the promise chain to something that does. Simplest way (if not passing it on) is to move the second handler passed to that final `.then` into a following `.catch` instead, so it handles that rejection caused by a `next` throw. (cc @DavidC)